How do I view the full error response in Angular?
I am trying to display more detailed error responses in my Angular app. It's running off of a .Net Core 8 backend.
I have the following code:
        <...>.subscribe(
            () => {
            },
            (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                this.busy = false;
                console.log(err);
                console.log(typeof(err));
                this.showErrorSheet('Error', '',
                    `While saving the user, the system encountered this error: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
            }
        );

When I run it with an intentional error (ex. a duplicate username) the err variable returns as a string reading

Http failure response for (url omitted): 400 OK

Meanwhile, the network tab in Chrome shows much more data. In addition to the 400 error code, the Response tab reads:

Username already in use

Which is the message I want to show.
On the .Net Core side, when the error is encountered, I am returning:
return BadRequest(errorMessage);

Where errorMessage is a string containing the error (in this case, "Username is already in use").
How can I show this message in Angular, so that I can display it to my users properly?

Hi @Chrygore, you add the code console.log(err);, have your check the Console tab in the browser?

Does your function <...> that returns Observable implement any logic that updates the response error with the catchError RxJS operator? Or is there any interceptor that does the same implementation as mentioned?

Get confused with your question, looks like you just need to return the error message from the response instead of "view the full error response".

@Rena yes, the console.log(err) returns the 400 message I mentioned above, and the console.log(typeof(err)) returns string, when I would expect it to return HttpErrorResponse or something of the sort.

The problem was that I had an overeager HttpInterceptor that was converting all HTTP error responses into a string.
The interceptor was simply returning:

err.statusText

Which was why I only saw a string, not an HttpErrorResponse object.

What is important is what structure the backend returns the error to you, what you need to do is to first understand the structure of the error and log it, and after seeing the log field, save it in a signal (or variable) and Use it. for example:
.subscribe({
  next: () => {
   //When backend is happy!
  },
  error: (error : HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(error.error)
    this.errorMessage.set(error.error.message)
  }
})

Maybe this will help you too!

Thanks for your response! In my case, the err object is identifying itself as a string, so I can't get any other information out of it. I'm not sure why it's coming out as a string, and not as an HttpErrorResponse.
